# How to convert volts to electrons?

Tags: electromagnetism, thermodynamics, electrons, charge, capacitance

The following table is taken from wikipedia here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johnson%E2%80%93Nyquist_noise#Thermal_noise_on_capacitors

I need to know how the third column which contains the number of electrons was calculated.

$$
\begin{array}{ | l | l | l | }
\hline
 \text{noise of capacitors at 300 K }& \sqrt{K_B T/C} & \text{Electrons} \\ \hline
 1 fF & 2 mV & 12.5 e− \\ \hline
 10 fF & 640 µV & 40 e− \\ \hline
 100 fF & 200 µV & 125 e− \\ \hline
 1 pF & 64 µV & 400 e− \\ \hline
 10 pF & 20 µV & 1250 e− \\ \hline
 100 pF & 6.4 µV & 4000 e− \\ \hline
 1 nF & 2 µV & 12500 e− \\ \hline
\end{array}
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$C = \frac QV$, so $Q = CV$.  It's just the product of the first two columns, with scaling for the units (where $e- = 1.6\times 10^{-19}C$).

$$1 fF \times 2mV = 2\times 10^{-18}C = 12.5 e-$$

Comment: Thanks! Is there something similar for resistance or inductance? I want to convert votage/current into electrons as well. I know that Q=R*time, and have been looking for an equation that relates voltage and charge. also is there a way to convert joules to coulombs?

Comment: That depends entirely on the situation.  The relation above is appropriate for capacitors.  Energy and charge aren't equal, but are related by voltage.  So you wouldn't "convert" from one to the other, but in the presence of  a constant voltage, could describe the energy in an amount of charge.  Look at the units of 1V.